# Jsso slider attribute "u" and validator

Tags: slider, jssor

Jassor Slider uses a custom attribute 'u' as show here

This throws html validation error saying "Attribute u not allowed on element ...". Is there any why to set html conform attribute instead of "u"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'data-u' instead of 'u' to define custom attribute.

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/pass-html-validation.html